# How to use my span tags so that it doesn't go to a new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add span tags so that I can add a red asterisk beside the email address text to show that it is required. However, Everytime I add a span tag it drops the asterisk down to the next line like so: [image]

Here is the section of code I am using for that column:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <h4>Email Address <span style="color:red;">*</span></h4>
        <p><input class="form-control" required name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" type="email" /></p>

    </div>
```

Can anyone help me with putting the asterisk on the same line as "email address"?

Comment: Please post a complete code example including the HTML and CSS so that we can see what's going on and re-create the issue.

Comment: Works ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9U26/

Comment: I don't see the problem I tried it out here and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/JRRL6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is a style in your "col-md-6" class. Please post the contents of that class and we can help you. I tried your code snippet in Chrome, FireFox and *sigh* Internet Explorer and they all worked without that class.

Just add

```
display: inline;
```

to your "col-md-6" class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `<span>` tag is `display:inline-block`. It seems that it has been set to `block` at an earlier point in your code.

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/s9U26/ it looks like it should work, so you aren't showing something.

You likely have this setting somewhere:

```
span{
    display: block;
}
```

Which causes the effect you see, change it to

```
span{
    display: inline;
}
```